# Meaning of "the flexible Chinese bamboo curtain was countered by a Western curtain of rigid disregard."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> For twenty two years China lay forgotten and was even confused with a small island, one of its provinces, **and the flexible Chinese bamboo curtain was countered by a Western curtain of rigid disregard**.

(Reference: CHINA'S WAY TO PROGRESS BY Galeazzo Santini)

What is the actual connotation of Chinese bamboo curtain and Western curtain of rigid disregard?

Comment: The metaphor of the curtain is about separation of geographical spaces and a way to not see what goes on inside a country. The Soviet Union was said to be behind the Iron Curtain.

Comment: It's an awkward mixed metaphor because curtains are almost always flexible, not rigid. While bamboo is intermediate in flexibility between something very flexible like a fabric curtain and something inflexible like a brick wall. So that might be some connotations. (I'm not sure you're using the word "connotation" correctly; I think you mean "what is the actual meaning..."?)

Answer (score 1):

“The bamboo curtain” is a metaphor for the barriers the People’s Republic of China put up around itself.  It’s an analogy to the “iron curtain” Winston Churchill said (in a famous speech from 1946)  that the Soviet Union had placed when it blocked the flow of people, information and commerce between Eastern and Western Europe:

> From Stettin in the Baltic to Trieste in the Adriatic, an iron curtain has descended across the Continent.

Google Ngrams shows the phrase “bamboo curtain” taking off after the Chinese revolution, peaking during the Korean War, gradually declining afterwards, and nearly disappearing after the U.S. and China re-opened diplomatic and trade relations.  A good example of historical usage in the U.S. [is this exchange from a congressional hearing from 1953,](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Overseas_Information_Programs_of_the_Uni/QRoSAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bamboo+curtain%22&pg=PA1293&printsec=frontcover) in which the head of the Asian section of the Voice of America is answering questions from a U.S. senator.

> Q: I think you used the picturesque phrase, “Bamboo Curtain.”
>
> A: That is right, sir.
>
> Q: What nations do you mean by those behind the Bamboo Curtain?
>
> A: Well, we consider Communist China or the mainland Chinese to be behind the Bamboo Curtain.
>
> Q: Is that the only nation you meant to include?
>
> A: That is right, sir.

One reason Senator Green might have asked for clarification is that the term was sometimes used for other Communist countries in Asia, and in at least one book I’ve found, even for Japan.

Here, the author is saying that Western disregard for China was another such barrier between the countries.  Furthermore, he is claiming that China’s laws were flexible (like bamboo), because the government would often make exceptions to them, but the West’s disregard was a constant.

Answer (score 0):

During the Cold War 'curtain' was used for for boundaries – physical or political between socialist and capitalist states. The Iron Curtain separated the Soviet Union from Western capitalist states. The Bamboo Curtain surrounded the People's Republic of China.